# kafka stream with oracle database with open source

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, open-source, apache-kafka-connect

My requirement is to connect oracle database as a source with kafka connect,I am looking some opensource tool so we can connect oracle database with kafka connect ,I don't want to use golden gate and other enterprise licences connector.can we use kafka producer with oracle database,please provide any link of blog or snnipet so I can use the same.

Comment: *Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, **tool, software library**, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow*

Comment: Kafka JDBC Connector is completely open source, btw... Does it not do what you want?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate Oracle and Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929205/how-to-integrate-oracle-and-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

[This blog](https://www.confluent.io/blog/no-more-silos-how-to-integrate-your-databases-with-apache-kafka-and-cdc) details the options you have available. You can use the open-source JDBC connector for Kafka Connect to connect to Oracle, but there are some trade-offs, as described in the article. Debezium are working on support for Oracle but currently it also requires a GoldenGate licence.

*Disclaimer: I work for Confluent, and I wrote the blog linked to.*