# streaming data from oracle with kafka

Tags: oracle, apache-kafka, data-stream

I'm starting with kafka and I need to control the inserts in a specific Oracle table, send the new records through kafka at the moment. I have no control over the database, so, in principle, Debizium is excluded. How can I do this? Without using triggers.

I've made a producer read data from Oracle with a java program in eclipse but, that would make constant requests to the database. I use java for simulated a ETL with consumer.

PS: I work with Windows but that's secondary.

Comment: kafka connect may fit your needs - https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/index.html

Comment: Kafka Connect JDBC Source would also have constant requests to your database... Not entirely sure what you're looking for. Debezium wouldn't "control inserts" either, as it reads the database events, not inserts them

Comment: For Debezium I need Golden Gate,don't I? It's an option or Confluent, as @aran says but, Confluente was giving me problems to install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to integrate Oracle and Kafka](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29929205/how-to-integrate-oracle-and-kafka)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your problem correctly, you are trying to route inserts from Kafka to Oracle Database. There could be few possibilities:

1. You implement Kafka consumer and as soon as your kafka cluster gets a message consumer makes a insert. You could reuse your java code here- just remove the polling part. Please visit [here](https://kafka.apache.org/10/javadoc/?org/apache/kafka/clients/consumer/KafkaConsumer.html)
2. If you have kafka deployed in a cloud environment and are using it as a service(aws msk) you would have the option to handling the events. Again you can use java program or can write a python script to make inserts.  Please visit [here](https://aws.amazon.com/msk/)
3. I would like to understand your throughput requirements, whether you really need kafka as a distributed messaging system or a simple aws sqs would work just fine. If you can use sqs things would be straightforward for you. You create a queue and you write a listener in
   [python or java](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/)

[boto3](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/sqs.html#SQS.Client.receive_message) is an excellent python library for working with sqs

Comment: I will read information about the technology mentioned. My throughput requirements? I need to control a table that can receive huge amounts of data. My intention is using a CDC (change data capture) and simulate ETL.